# Праздник Пасха(и)

Tags: орфография

Радуница отмечается во вторник, на девятый день после религиозного праздника Пасха(и)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректно: "праздника Пасхи". 
Но вообще-то я бы немного поправил фразу. Слово "религиозный" здесь явно лишнее.

Comment: Почему лишнее?

Comment: Потому что избыточно.

Comment: Потому что слово Пасха общеизвестное и уже подразумевает религию?

Comment: Ну можно и так сформулировать... 
Если вы действительно хотите получить от меня конкретный ответ, то я бы ответил так, что оно не добавляет ни смысла, ни понимания, ни выразительности. И звучит почти уничижительно.

Добро бы было "главного христианского праздника".

Comment: Соглашусь, что он не добавляет ничего из перечисленного, но не понимаю, почему уничижительно.